# To remove the previous pages from stack in angular routing

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, and I want to try building my app on it. I just have a normal two pages app. I can see that the routing behaves normal, but I can see that when I press back from the keyboard, I come back to the login page.

`login -> homepage`, **back button pressed** `homepage -> login`

Now I want the login page to be removed from the stack, so when we hit on the keyboard back, it does nothing. Like removing the previous page from the stack every time you visit such page. I don't want my user to come back to the `login page` without logging out.

**Home Page:**

```
//going to the home page with this click on the button 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>

submit(){
 (<any> window).location = '/home';
}
```

Same for the `logout`, I am just doing the same thing:

**Logout:**

```
<div class="logout-link col-4">
   <a routerLink="/">Logout</a>
</div>
```

What I have tried so far is doing this:

```
//homepage logout button
[routerlink] = "['/', {clearhistory: true}]" //This disabled the route functioning at all, I could not go to home by tapping on the logout button.

//loginpage submit button
submit(){
  this.route.navigate(['/home'], {clearhistory: true}) //did nothing I can again come back with the keyboard back
}
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The option you're looking for is [replaceUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl). That will replace the state in history and you won't be able to go back to the previous URL.

Alternatively, you can also use [skipLocationChange](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#skipLocationChange) to navigate without pushing state into history at all.

```
this.route.navigate(['/home'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for that answer only. One more question is there any way to add the same in the HTML file in `routerLink` cos it throws an error when I do this: `<a [routerLink]="['/', {replaceUrl: true}]">`

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the navigation extras can only be used when navigating programmatically, not at the template level.

Comment: <div  [replaceUrl]="true"  [routerLink]="['/home']" > Like this </div>